# How to create hex editor inside of winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm still confused whats better to use, datagridview or Be.HexEditor,
I am pretty sure I'll be able to do it with datagridview, but I like  be.hex more, especially speed, UI etc...

But I tried to understand the code of be.hex, and I can't figure out how does it work, and also is it possible to show values from bytes arrays to the HexBox(not only from opening `.bin` files). it also uses `dynamicFileByteProvider`, and there is no info on the net about this class.

```
dynamicFileByteProvider = new DynamicFileByteProvider(fileName);
dynamicFileByteProvider.Changed += new EventHandler(byteProvider_Changed);
dynamicFileByteProvider.LengthChanged += new EventHandler(byteProvider_LengthChanged);
```

my app will open 1024 bytes files max, and also it will read bytes from comm port

Comment: Please [edit] the question in such a way that there is a *clear question* with a *limited scope*. "How to create hex editor" to me is an enormous scope. I also can't see how it relates in any way to the very few lines of code that you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tinkered a bit with this. What I did was

1) put an invisible picture box as control placeholder on the form, here named ph1

2) configure the HexBox control in Form_Load()

```
private HexBox hexBox;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hexBox = new HexBox()
    {
        Top = ph1.Top,
        Width = ph1.Width,
        Height = ph1.Height,
        Left = ph1.Left,
        Visible = true,
        UseFixedBytesPerLine = true,
        BytesPerLine = 16,
        ColumnInfoVisible = true,
        LineInfoVisible = true,
        StringViewVisible = true,
        VScrollBarVisible = true
    };
    this.Controls.Add(hexBox);
    this.Controls.Remove(ph1);
}
```

3) Load the actual file in DragDrop event

```
var filePath = ((string[])(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)))[0];
var source = new FileByteProvider(filePath);
hexBox.ByteProvider = source;
hexBox.Refresh();
```

Example after drag/drop of a docx file onto the form:

[image]

**Edit: if you wish to provide some self-generated array of bytes, it is as simple as this:**

```
byte[] byteArr = {0xaa, 0x3f, 0x4b};
hexBox.ByteProvider = new DynamicByteProvider(byteArr);
```

**Edit 2: To save the contents of the hex box:**
I am sure there is some better way to do this. What I found for now is to simply add a handler in the hex box definition block:

```
hexBox.CopiedHex += HexBox_CopiedHex;
```

Have some kind of "save" button with such a code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hexBox.SelectAll();
    hexBox.CopyHex();
    hexBox.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

And such an event handler:

```
private void HexBox_CopiedHex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hex = Clipboard.GetText();
    var hexHex = hex.Split(' ');
    var hexArr = new byte[hexHex.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < hexHex.Length; i++)
    {
        hexArr[i] = byte.Parse(hexHex[i], NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\00_Work\test.bin", hexArr);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your anser, but what it actually does?

Comment: i need to be able to put bytes array in the hexbox, not only from openning a bin file

Comment: Did you try it? That's exactly what this does! I'll put a screenshot in my answer.
You need to show a little more effort.

Comment: I think now I know what you mean. I have adjusted my answer accordingly, see the edit.

Comment: Also, how can i save file after i  provided some self-generated array of bytes? Seems like it can save file only which was opened before. But how to create .bin file and write values on it from hexbox

Comment: Go ahead and play! Try some things out! Try with `hexBox.ByteProvider.ApplyChanges();` and `hexBox.SelectAll();` followed by `CopyHex();`  ... Whatever. Knock yourself out and especially: *find* out. Much more fun. :-)

Comment: thanks a lot for your attention to the thread. I didnt get where i have to put hexBox.CopiedHex += HexBox_CopiedHex; But anyway i tried  to convert the hex string which we copy with var hex = Clipboard.GetText(); then removed spaces with   hex = hex.Replace(" ", string.Empty); then converted it to the bytes array  byte[] testarray;
            testarray = StringToByteArray(test_string);

Comment: Either something wrong in your `StringToByteArray` or using StreamWriter for a byte array, when you should use `File.WriteAllBytes`. See edited event handler.

Comment: From where you installed the plugin? From nugget `Be.Windows.Forms.HexBox` ?  
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Be.Windows.Forms.HexBox#readme-body-tab

Answer (score 0):

To show byte[] in hexbox use `new DynamicByteProvider(byte[]`

To get modified byte[] from hexbox
use `DynamicByteProvider.Bytes.ToArray()`